# How to Null two or more value by ID Dynamically IN JQUERY or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

By clicking on a button,  value of id is not getting set dynamically on multiple id's. So please can you give us the solution

```
<html>
  <body>

    <h1 id="myHeaderqda">Hello World!</h1>
    <h1 id="myHeaderwasd">Hello World!</h1>
    <h1 id="myHeadereasd">Hello World!</h1>
     <button onclick="displayResult()">Change text</button>

  <script>
    function displayResult() {
       document.getElementById("myHeader*").innerHTML = "";
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you do it by using class ?

Comment: we have not getting any idea how to do with class so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to search by id part you need to use more sophisticated attribute selector combined with `querySelectorAll`.

Like this

```js
function displayResult() {
  [].forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('[id^=myHeader]'),
    function(el) {
      el.innerHTML = 'Changed: ' + new Date()
    }
  )
}
```

```html
<h1 id="myHeaderqda">Hello World!</h1>
<h1 id="myHeaderwasd">Hello World!</h1>
<h1 id="myHeadereasd">Hello World!</h1>
<button onclick="displayResult()">Change text</button>
```

Or better use class instead

```js
    function displayResult() {
      [].forEach.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName('my-header'),
        function(el) {
          el.innerHTML = 'Changed: ' + new Date()
        }
      )
    }
```

```html
    <h1 id="myHeaderqda" class="my-header">Hello World!</h1>
    <h1 id="myHeaderwasd" class="my-header">Hello World!</h1>
    <h1 id="myHeadereasd" class="my-header">Hello World!</h1>
    <button onclick="displayResult()">Change text</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Yury Tarabanko